# The parameters are not updated using multi-gpu training

Tags: python, tensorflow

### Solved... I found a bug in average_gradients() function

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np


from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)


learning_rate = 0.0001

training_iters = 100000

batch_size = 32

display_step = 10

num_gpus = 1


n_input = 784

n_classes = 10 

dropout = 0.75 



def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):

    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)


def maxpool2d(x, k=2):


    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')


def average_gradients(tower_grads):

    average_grads = []
    for grad_and_vars in zip(*tower_grads):
    # Note that each grad_and_vars looks like the following:
    #   ((grad0_gpu0, var0_gpu0), ... , (grad0_gpuN, var0_gpuN))
        grads = []
        for g, _ in grad_and_vars:
      # Add 0 dimension to the gradients to represent the tower.
            expanded_g = tf.expand_dims(g, 0)

      # Append on a 'tower' dimension which we will average over below.
            grads.append(expanded_g)

    # Average over the 'tower' dimension.
            grad = tf.concat(0, grads)
            grad = tf.reduce_mean(grad, 0)

    # Keep in mind that the Variables are redundant because they are shared
    # across towers. So .. we will just return the first tower's pointer to
    # the Variable.
    v = grad_and_vars[0][1]
    grad_and_var = (grad, v)
    average_grads.append(grad_and_var)
    return average_grads




def conv_net(images, dropout):
    # Reshape input picture
    images = tf.reshape(images, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])

    # Convolution Layer
    with tf.variable_scope('conv1'):
        W = tf.get_variable('weights', [5, 5, 1, 32], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
        b = tf.get_variable("biases", [32], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
        conv1 = conv2d(images, W, b)
        # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
        conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    # Convolution Layer
    with tf.variable_scope('conv2'):
        W = tf.get_variable('weights', [5, 5, 32, 64], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
        b = tf.get_variable("biases", [64], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
    # Max Pooling (down-sampling)
        conv2 = conv2d(conv1, W, b)
        conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, 7*7*64])

    with tf.variable_scope('fully'):
        weights = tf.get_variable('weights', [7*7*64, 1024], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
        bias = tf.get_variable('bias', [1024], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
        fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights), bias)
        fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    # Apply Dropout
        fc1 = tf.nn.dropout(fc1, dropout)

    # Output, class prediction

    with tf.variable_scope('softmax'):
        weights = tf.get_variable('weights', [1024, 10], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
        bias = tf.get_variable('bias', [10], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())     
        out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights), bias)

    return out




def train():

    with tf.Graph().as_default():

        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size*num_gpus, 784])
        y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size*num_gpus, n_classes])
        keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) #dropout (keep probability)

        global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)


        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
        tower_grads = []
        for i in xrange(num_gpus):
            with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
                with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % ('MNIST', i)) as scope:
          # Calculate the loss for one tower of the CIFAR model. This function
          # constructs the entire CIFAR model but shares the variables across
          # all towers
          # Reuse variables for the next tower.

                    next_batch = x[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size, :]
                    next_label_batch = y[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size, :]
                    pred = conv_net(next_batch, keep_prob)

                    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, next_label_batch))


                    correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(next_label_batch, 1))
                    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

                    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()

          # Calculate the gradients for the batch of data on this CIFAR tower.
                    grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(cost)
          # Keep track of the gradients across all towers.
                    tower_grads.append(grads)



        grads = average_gradients(tower_grads)
        apply_gradient_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)


        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()


        with tf.Session() as sess:

            sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
            allow_soft_placement=True,
            log_device_placement=True))
            sess.run(init)
            saver = tf.train.Saver()
            var = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables()][0]
            aa = sess.run(var)
            np.save('initial.npy', aa)
            step = 1
    # Keep training until reach max iterations
            while step * (num_gpus*batch_size) < training_iters:

                large_input = np.zeros((num_gpus*batch_size, n_input))
                large_labels = np.zeros((num_gpus*batch_size, n_classes))
        
                for index in xrange(num_gpus):
                    batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
                    large_input[index*batch_size:(index+1)*batch_size, :] = batch_x
                    large_labels[index*batch_size:(index+1)*batch_size, :] = batch_y

        # Run optimization op (backprop)
                sess.run(apply_gradient_op, feed_dict={x: large_input, y: large_labels,
                                       keep_prob: dropout})
                if step % display_step == 0:
            # Calculate batch loss and accuracy
                    loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: large_input,
                                                              y: large_labels,
                                                              keep_prob: 1.})
                    print("Iter " + str(step*num_gpus*batch_size) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.5f}".format(acc))
                step += 1
            print("Optimization Finished!")

            var = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables()][0]
            aa = sess.run(var)
            np.save('final.npy', aa)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()
```

Comment: I'm a beginner of Tensorflow and wrote a piece of code to test on the MNIST dataset. I find that during training my parameters doesn't change at all and cannot find the problem, so SOS!!!

Comment: Did you try the TensorFlow tutorials on MNIST? https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.html and https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html (choose one depending on your level of experience with ML)

Comment: @Neal  Hi Neal, I have tried the basic implementation on MNIST and it's all OK. Then I tried to implement based on the CIFAR10 tutorial (using multi-gpu training) and tested the code on MNIST, I found that the parameters doesn't change during training phase.

Comment: Just noticed you aren't using the GradientDescentOptimizer?

Comment: @Neal  Solved... I found a bug in average_gradients() function, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi @Bohan Zhuang , could you please update your result, or post a answer by yourself?